# The maximum amount of all values for a given alphabet and a text of length N

Tags: algorithms

Say, I have a code/password like this:

```
abcde123 --> 8 characters
```

Where only letters and digits are allowed. How do I calculate the amount of all its possible values? I'm doing this the following way:

```
1) 26 letters + 10 digits = 36 full alphabet
2) 8 length ** 36 full alphabet = 324518553658426726783156020576256 values
```

Is this correct?

Comment: 36 choices for the first character, 36 choices for the second character, ... means it's `(alphabet size) ** (string length)`.

Comment: @4castle and what did I say?

Comment: You said the opposite: `(string length) ** (alphabet size)`. They are very different numbers.

Comment: "Where only letters and digits are allowed". Why? This is an insane restriction. Don't do that to your users, please.

Comment: @DavidArno Why?

Comment: @RobbieDee, why, what?

Comment: @DavidArno Sorry, I mean why do you think this is an insane restriction?

Comment: @RobbieDee, for two reasons: one, any restriction on passwords makes for an unpleasant user experience, eg anyone using a secure password generator and store must reconfigure it to the rules of site. Two, it needlessly makes the passwords easier to hack. [Even five years ago, a 25 GPU cluster could be used to crack any Windows password in under six hours](https://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/). An eight character password limited to letters and numbers would take just 11 minutes to crack with that system.

Comment: @RobbieDee, the third reason is that any such restriction is often a strong indication that passwords are being stored in plain text, rather than being properly salted and hashed and should make one nervous of using that password "protected" service.

Comment: @DavidArno All true of course, but there are problem domains that get by on a far smaller character set than that - mobile phones and ATMs being just two. In these cases, mechanisms are usually in place to limit the efficacy of brute force attacks.

Comment: @DavidArno, I will do.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting that `a <> A` so as long as your password system is case dependent you have A-Za-z0-9 as possible characters, (in the ASCII letters and numbers), which gives 62 possible characters for each position - if your password is a fixed length, say 8 this gives:

```
62 ** 8 = 218,340,105,584,896
```

possible combinations.

The basic rule is that each character has 62 possiblities, (more or less depending on the actual language alphabet and what are classed as letters), so for the first you have 62 possibilities, for the second another 62 so 62*62 and so on.

Of course if you have a variable length password of up to N characters the formula is:

```
sum(62**n for n in 0..N)
```

This gives:

```
1  Length 0 has only one possibility
62 Length 1
3,844
238,328
14,776,336
916,132,832
56,800,235,584
3,521,614,606,208
218,340,105,584,896
-------------------
221,919,451,578,091
-------------------
```

Comment: Perfect! Worth to mention for helping  OP to never forget the formula: the first char has 62 possibility; for each of these 62 possibilities, the second char offers 62 more possibilities, that is 62*62 possibilities in total; and so on, which leads to 62*62*....*62 (i.e n times for n chars in the password) = 62 ^ n. Of course, this assumes that the password is of fixed length ;-)